# Ruby Module name conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've grouped a set of controllers in a folder called: "Foursquare", the class declaration with the module name looks like this: Foursquare::BadgesController. Inside this controllers I want to call methods from the Foursquare gem that also has the Foursquare Module:

```
class Foursquare::BadgesController < ApplicationController
   def search
     user = Foursquare::User.new(session[:access_token])
   end
end
```

So it doesn't work.

Is there any option besides renaming the controller's Module name ?

Comment: Instead of saying "It doesn't work" you should tell us what error message or unexpected behavior you get!

Comment: The error is: uninitialized constant Foursquare::User . Also I want to clarify that I don't want my controller on the same module as the Foursquare gem, I was hoping I could have the same module name with some kind of separation. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't it work? Nothing says you can't insert your own classes into the Foursquare module space. Not that it's necessarily a good idea, but the language allows it no problem.

Comment: Are you sure you included the Foursquare gem in your Rails project, and that you are using it correctly? In any case..I would rename your own module name to not be the same as the gem module name. It's not a good idea to have them both in the same space..you're asking for a nosebleed sooner or later..as you probably guessed yourself too.

Comment: I agree I should rename it. Thanks very much